# Updates/Deletes in levelDB

Tags: key-value-store, leveldb

The sorted SSTable data structure that levelDB uses is immutable. If so, how are records updated/deleted in levelDB ? Is this process done periodically ?

Answer (score 0):

http://leveldb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/impl.html is short and covers these questions. See the compaction section especially.